# Error encountered while installing SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to install SQL Server on my machine that has windows XP. During installation system encounters an error while installing MSXML 6 Service Pack 2 (KB954459) and SQL server installation fails. I researched on web and people have recommended using utility at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301 to uninstall MSXML and then try again. Unfortunately MS has removed the utility from that link.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Just click on the download on the page.

http://web.archive.org/web/20050329041601/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing MSXML SP2 manually?

Run its installer from the SQL Server 2005 media, and you'll have a better chance of understanding and solving the error you're getting from the SQL Server setup. Or, if it "just works", SQL Server will skip that step because it'll be already installed.